# How to prevent other hosts on the same LAN from seeing my IP and host name?

Tags: identity, arp-spoofing

I want to hide my computer IP dan hostname when I am online on the same LAN on which other computers running netcut and other network tools. I have installed netcut defender but it seems not to hide my identity.

Is it possible to hide my identity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I disagree with [tylerl's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45689/how-to-prevent-other-hosts-on-the-same-lan-from-seeing-my-ip-and-host-name/45690#45690). It is indeed difficult to hide our IP from other hosts on a LAN, **it's very possible**.

Because you're mentioning [netcut](http://www.arcai.com/arcai-netcut-faq.html) (a tool that works by using ARP poisoning), I think you have the following setup:

- You trying to use the Internet.
- Router giving you access to the Internet.
- Other hosts on the same LAN.
- Some malicious hosts trying to cut off your Internet connection.

The idea is quite simple: All you need is to block **all** inbound connections to your computer and all broadcast communications from your computer. This requires a slight knowledge of the network (at least the router's MAC and IP address) as you'll have drop all ARP requests (in and out). The only thing left to do is configure the router's IP address as your gateway and only communicate with it.

That method will indeed keep you hidden on the network as only the router will know of your existence. It will also protect you from netcut as your IP will not show on other hosts' ARP tables. **However**, this will not protect you from *other* ARP poisoning attacks that can spy on your connection and even completely cut you off.

Comment: Could you give an example how to configure my computer to make the router the only device knows me?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot Sorry, no. This is outside the scope of our site. But, I'll give you some leads. You can use any advanced firewall application (ZoneAlarm, for example) and write your own rules for the communications you want to block. To craft your own packets, you can use tools such as [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

Comment: Additionally, you can also turn off automatic ARP on your host and use static ARP entries. Also, adding a static ARP entry for your host on router will be even better.

Comment: @Adnan told ya so

Comment: Basically if you block all ethernet traffic destined to any MAC address other than the gateway, you'll be mostly-invisible to anyone who isn't trying very hard (e.g. spoofing their MAC to match the gateway). I don't know if this is possible under Windows, but Linux can do it pretty easily with the built-in tools.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no. As a rule, your IP is visible to anyone on your LAN, which sort of is the definition of what a LAN is.